# Как сделать так, что бы бот пересылал сообщение пользователя телеграм мне, а я ответив на него говорил, что бот ответит ему

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Мне нужно, что бы бот получив сообщение от пользователя пересылал его мне, а я ответив на него, грубо сказать, говорил, что бот ответит пользователю

Comment: Думаю для начала стоит прописать логаритм с строго прописанными действиями. После попробовать реализовать на питоне. А то очень "размытый" вопрос, не получается не помочь , не дать ответа

Comment: Я могу вам написать логаритм, но увы я не работаю с апи телеграмма и с питоном ( хотя диплом на нём написал)

Answer (score 4):

на скорую руку

```
adm = 123  # Telegram id


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введи сообщение')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, forward_adm)


def forward_adm(message):
    print('forward_adm')
    print(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(adm, '{}'.format(message.text))
    forward_usr(message)


def forward_usr(message):
    print('forward_usr')
    print(message.chat.id)
    global usr_id
    usr_id = message.chat.id

    msg = bot.send_message(adm, 'введи ответ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, forward_usr_1)


def forward_usr_1(message):
    print('forward_usr_1')
    print(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(usr_id, '{}'.format(message.text))


# Запуск бота
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без global - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282213/234134