# Простой чат на базе Telegram Bot'a (Python, telebot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Необходимо реализовать следующее: пользователь пишет текстовое сообщение боту.

Его идентификатор (далее - `id`) сравнивается с `id` админа, если `id` не совпадает (т.е. боту пишет не админ, а простой пользователь), то сообщение отправляется админу.

Если `id` совпадает (т.е. боту пишет админ), то сообщение отправляется пользователю. Получается, что бот здесь - платформа для обратной связи.

Проблема: когда пишет админ - сообщение отправляется ему же (см. блок кода после `else`).

Сам код:

```
import telebot
import key 
import logging

#TOKEN
token = key.token
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

#DEBUG OF MESSAGES
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#CHAT WHICH GET MESSAGES (ADMINS' CHATS)
admin_chat = "453081342"

#TRIGGER COMMANDS
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Старт...")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.chat.id != admin_chat:
        bot.send_message(admin_chat, message.text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пожалуйста, предоставьте максимально простое и понятное решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Сохраняйте id пользователя и отправляйте сообщение этому id.

Comment: Если id произвольный? Т.е. боту может написать любой пользователь.

Comment: В зависимости от того, с кем сейчас говорит админ, ему и отправляйте, заранее сохраняя его id. К примеру, человек написал, Вы сразу сохранили его id и потом сообщение админа отправляете этому id.

Comment: Что-то вроде этого? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1109631/234134

Answer (score 2):

возможно, уже неактуально, но я столкнулась с похожей проблемой.
Всё дело в синтаксисе:

```py
    admin_chat = "453081342"
```

эту запись Python читает, как строку, и это работает здесь:

```py
    bot.send_message(admin_chat, message.text)
```

но здесь ему необходимо число:

```py
    if message.chat.id != admin_chat:
```

поэтому для Python `message.chat.id` всегда  `!= admin_chat`.
Нужно просто убрать `"`:

```py
    admin_chat = 453081342
```