# Каким образом избавиться от global в коде?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Имеется простой echo скрипт для общения с ботом. В методах использовал global, чтобы изменить переменные. Подскажите хорошую замену для этой процедуры, чтобы обойтись локальными переменными или может быть чем-то еще. Сколько я не пытался что-либо придумать, ничего не выходит. Опыта маловато пока.
Исходный код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('180*:AA*M')

name = ''
surname = ''
age = 0


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == "/reg":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "What's your name?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Write /reg")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "I'm remember this, but this is not exactly")
    elif call.data == "no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Mda")


def get_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "What's your surname?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surname)


def get_surname(message):
    global surname
    surname = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "How old are you?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age)


def get_age(message):
    global age
    while age == 0:
        try:
            age = int(message.text)

        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Numerals please")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Yes", callback_data="yes")
    keyboard.add(key_yes)
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="No", callback_data="no")
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = "You are " + str(age) + " old, your name is " + name + " " + surname + "?"
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Писать всё в ассоциативную коллекцию/БД, где ключом будет `message.from_user.id`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов ассоциативная коллекция будет не глобальной переменной? и как к ассоциативной коллекции без global обратитесь?

Comment: сделать класс и обращаться к его атрибутам

Comment: @Интик хорошая мысль, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @RomanKonoval, ассоциативная коллекция тоже будет глобальная, но не понадобится вызывать `global` в каждой функции, чтобы меня ее ключи. Но лучше сразу в базе делать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще, можно передавать из шага в шаг с помощью третьего аргумента:
`bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, message.text)`

Пример:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите *название организации*', parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите *ФИО заявителя*', parse_mode='Markdown')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, message.text)


def start_3(message, company):
    last = message.text.split()[0]
    first = message.text.split()[1]
    middle = message.text.split()[2]

    phone_btn = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    phone_btn.add(types.KeyboardButton(text='Отправить номер', request_contact=True))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажмите кнопку *Отправить номер* ниже', parse_mode='Markdown',
                           reply_markup=phone_btn)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_4, first, last, middle, company)


def start_4(message, first, last, middle, company):
    if message.contact is not None:
        start_5(message, first, last, middle, company, message.contact.phone_number)


def start_5(message, first, last, middle, company, phone):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваши данные:\n{}\n{} {} {}\n{}'.format(company, last, first, middle, phone),
                     reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209804/234134

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: Если ответ является решением Вашего вопроса, отметьте его таковым, это поможет другим участникам.