# Как боту продолжить диалог с юзером Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Всем привет! Появилась задача: нужно что бы бот продолжал вести диалог с пользователем. Что то по типу:

```
юзер:/start
бот: привет напиши мне свое имя
юзер: *вводит свое имя*
бот: спасибо я запомню
```

Как реализовать?
Заранее спасибо за внимание к вопросу!

Answer (score 0):

Держи

P.S. Лучше используй **telebot** вместо aiogram. Для твоих задач самое то

```css
import telebot 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start(message):
    if  message.text.lower() == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, напиши мне свое имя")  
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, foo)
        
    if  message.text.lower() == "/name":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Твоё имя: {name}") 
  
def foo(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.lower()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо, я запомню")
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: 'global' такое себе, лучше дополнительным аргументом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282213/234134

Comment: Я знаю как использовать библиотеку telebot. Мне нужно именно  в библиотеке aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Используйте машину состояний.

louder.py

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class Start(StatesGroup):
start_name= State()
```

main.py

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from louser import Start # импортирую класс "Start" из файла "louder.py"


# Команда /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
      await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Как тебя зовут?')
await Start.start_name.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Start.start_name)
async def namee(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
      name = message.text
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f'Спасибо за ответ\nТебя зовут: {name}')
```

Это пример кода. Но лучше почитать документацию.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]