# Используя global*название переменной* бот телеграм принимает данные разных людей

Tags: telebot, бот, telegram

Когда бот принимает данные у 2 человек одновременно, данные начинают смешиваться. Как я понял (новичок), вся проблема находится в том, что у переменных стоят пометки global. Есть ли пометки, которые будут работать у каждого человека? nonlocal - не работает. Пример кода снизу. Python 3.5.8+, pyTelegramBotApi[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В следующий раз добавляйте код в вопрос в виде текста, так с ним проще работать и соответственно помогать. А вообще это уже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282213/234134

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, голос за него не будет лишним.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте словарь с помощью global и записывайте данные с ключом id пользователя.
P. S. Не советую постить код изображением, в некоторых случаях это не удобно для тех, кто отвечает, лучше просто постите код или часть код в самом вопросе, или заливайте его на pastebin.

Comment: У бота есть контексты. Пастебин на со не приветствуется - код лучше оставить в вопросе или на гитхабе