# Как получить сохраняемое значение в методе register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telebot

Я знаю, что с помощью register_next_step_handler можно регистрировать следующее сообщение пользователя, знаю как его сохранять, но как его получить ?
Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def choice_button(message):
    if message.text == 'Выбрать тег':
        msg = bot.send_message(getChatId(message), text='Напишите теги для поиска в одном сообщение через запятую')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, input_tags)

def input_tags(message):
   tags = message.text.split(' ')
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. У вас в `tags` как раз эти данные, не?

Comment: И почему вы делаете сплит по пробелу если требуете разделять запятой

Comment: Что то сделать хотел. tags нужно получить, чтоб дальше с ним работать, потому что оно сохраняется только в методе. Решение я уже нашел. Просто нужно сделать эту переменную глобальной

Comment: Тогда закрывайте вопрос, он бесползен для других

Comment: global зло. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282213/234134

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно сделать эту переменную глобальной